# How to combine multiple ggplots into one plot with same x and y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to combine multiple ggplots into one plot with same x and y axis. This is my [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hhY_f_-7akhZqBwqnBUK4IBawaRwvVS3z8_vSN7opbE/edit?usp=sharing). I have one Time column and 6 trend columns (A_Trnd, B_Trnd, C_Trnd etc). I have generated plot for Time vs A_Trnd.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

result <- read.csv("Downloads/Questions Trend - Questions Trend.csv")
result$Time_Formatted <- as.Date(result$Time_Formatted)
date_breaks <- as.Date(c("9/1/08", "5/12/14", "7/1/17", "2/2/19", "6/3/20"), "%m/%d/%y")
p1 <- ggplot(result, aes(result$Time_Formatted, result$A_Trnd)) + 
     geom_point(size = 0.1) + xlab("Month") + ylab("Temporal Trend") +
    scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks , date_labels = "%Y-%m", limits = c(as.Date("2008-08-01"), as.Date("2021-08-01"))) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 70, vjust = 0.9, hjust = 1))
p1 + geom_smooth(method = "loess", color = "red")
```

Now, I want to plot the same for **Time vs B_Trnd**, **Time vs C_Trnd** and have a combine plot like below.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: For the multi-plot you've shown you'll need to use ggplot [facets](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html).

Comment: For my data, will facets work since I will plot X vs A, X vs B, X vs C where A, B, C are separate column in my data?

Comment: Like this? https://cln.sh/PV1d5o

Comment: @rdelrossi, Yes

Comment: Looks like Zhiqiang Wang beat me to the punch, but his solution is pretty much like what I have here. You've already done the hard part. Just need to pivot your data and add the `facet_grid()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
result <-read.csv("Downloads/Questions Trend - Questions Trend.csv") %>% 
  mutate(Time = as.Date(Time, format = "%m/%d/%y")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Time, names_to = "group", values_to = "value") 
date_breaks <- as.Date(c("9/1/08", "5/12/14", "7/1/17", "2/2/19", "6/3/20"), "%m/%d/%y")
p1 <- ggplot(result, aes(Time, value)) + 
  geom_point(size = 0.1) + 
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Temporal Trend") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks , date_labels = "%Y-%m", limits = c(as.Date("2008-08-01"), as.Date("2021-08-01"))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 70, vjust = 0.9, hjust = 1), 
 legend.position = "none")  + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", aes(color = group)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(group), nrow = 1)
p1
```

[image]